# Who is "get working xterm" / why can't I see user profile?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

In this thread, there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1076845/447356) from "get working xterm".  Why can't I click on the username?

[copy and paste from terminal with keyboard in linux (ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761807/copy-and-paste-from-terminal-with-keyboard-in-linux-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an account that no longer exists.